# Can a Razor _Layout view only be applied to Pages that inherit from a particular interface?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm interested in adding an "add to dashboard" feature to a set of pages that have functionality I determine by reflection (an `[attribute]` or a `IMyFeatureOrSolution`.)

Rather than identifying which pages need to use a different `~/shared/_Layout.cshtml`, I'd like to use a different approach that keeps things "OOP-y".

If my idea is possible, is it a bad idea (Asp.core performance, caching, memory impact on many different or similar pages)?

What's the right way to implement this, or what other notes and caveats exist? (Or did I miss a day in class where "The Better Approach" was shared in school?)

> If supported in Razor pages, because IPersonalData exists on this page,
> controller (or data [attribute], etc, in theory...) then data would be
>
> - automatically protected in a set of ways (encryption, subsitution, differential ngram, changing index numbers
>   (bool:discardmap|bool:detectNew,bool:applydiffupdates))
> - link to ASP.NET's authentication pages that include export of private data. Request deletion, or other status which might need
>   approval workflows (finra email host, as if they would use a default
>   template, but it helps the customer think well)
> - ^is a three ^^^ in software for/as/by example

Answer (score 1):

Generally, we could change the layout by [setting the Layout property on the view page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0#specifying-a-layout).

> Can a Razor _Layout view only be applied to Pages that inherit from a
> particular interface?

Yes, you can change the Layout based on whether the page model is inherited from a particular Interface. To achieve it, please refer to the following steps:

First, you could use the Type.IsAssignableFrom() method to check if page model is inherited from a particular Interface, code as below:

Here, I Add an About page with AboutModel, and inherited from the IMyCustomInterface interface, code in the About.cshtml.cs page:

```
public class AboutModel : PageModel, IMyCustomInterface
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        var isInherit = typeof(IMyCustomInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(AboutModel));
        
        ViewData["IsInherit"] = isInherit;
    }
}
```

Then, in the About view page (About.cshtml), we could get the result from the ViewData, then, according to the condition to set the Layout property:

```
@{
    if (ViewData["IsInherit"] != null)
    {

        var isInherit = (bool)ViewData["IsInherit"];
        if (isInherit)
        {
            Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; //using default layout 
        }
        else
        {
            Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_MyCustomLayout.cshtml"; //using custom layout
        }

    }
}
```

For the performance issue, in my opinion, by using above method, we are just used to to check if page model is inherited from a particular Interface, so, it is perfectly acceptable and you won't notice any delay with it.